# How to select the elements of a numpy array without using loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am doing crossover, so i want to replace the elements of matrix (m1) with another matrix (m2) [Image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWAu1.png)(elements in green box has to be replaced).
How to do this without using loop?

Comment: Don't use images for examples please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your both arrays contain:

```
a:                           b:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],     array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],            [104, 105, 106, 107],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])           [108, 109, 110, 111]])
```

and you want to copy elements from *a* to *b* through the "filter"
that you defined.

To do it, create a mask:

- of size just like *a*, initially filled with *0*,
- fill left upper corner (2 rows by 2 columns) with *1*.

The code to do it is:

```
msk = np.zeros_like(a)
msk[0:2, 0:2] = 1
```

So its content is:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And now copy *b* to *a* through this mask:

```
a = np.where(msk, a, b)
```

getting:

```
array([[  0,   1, 102, 103],
       [  4,   5, 106, 107],
       [108, 109, 110, 111]])
```

As you wish, without any loop.

Another solution (a one-liner) is:

```
a = np.where(np.array([[1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]), a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use fancy indexing for that. Either use the elements of m1 to replace it in m2 or the other way round.

```
m3 = m2.copy()
m3[:2,:2] = m1[:2,:2]
```